# What is the point of making an argument an array by default?

Tags: ruby

Sometimes, when a method needs to be given an array as an argument, I see the method defined like this:

```
def method(argument = [])
  ... 
end
```

I don't understand why `= []` is used. As far as I can see, it adds nothing. If you did supply an array as an argument, the method would run either way, and if you didn't, it would throw an error either way. Is it just convention? Or is it perhaps a visual aid so the programmer can easily see what type of data a method requires?

Comment: You are wrong: if you do not supply an argument in this case, it will _not_ give an error, it will just do nothing.

Comment: Sorry, there was some ambiguity in that sentence. I meant if you did not supply an array as an argument, not if you did not supply an argument at all.

Comment: The default parameter is only relevant when _not_ supplying an argument. It will not overrule any given argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set default argument here, it won't raise an error if you call this method without arguments:

```
method
# => []
```

Comment: Ohhh I see. Yes that makes total sense! Duh. PS Sorry I can't upvote your answer because my reputation isn't high enough.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a default value allows you to call the method with AND without that param.

I have found it helpful while adding a new variable to an existing method. If I specify a default value to the new variable, I don't have to worry about changing the previous calls to that method which have only the previous set of variables. If, however, I am not able to specify a default value for the new variable, I will have to go through the code and hunt down all the method calls, and modify it to include the new variable.